# How put an image in ace:linkButton instead text value (icefaces)?

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I'm trying to insert an image that will work like a button. With component ice:commandLink all work fine.

```
<ice:commandLink partialSubmit="true"
                         title="#{controller.description}"
                         actionListener="#{controller.actionPerformed}"
                         styleClass="toolbarButtonText"
                         immediate="#{controller.action.immediate}"
        >
            <h:graphicImage value="#{controller.icon!=null?(controller.icon):(sessionContext.styleManager.zeroIcon)}"
                            border="0" alt="#{controller.description}"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{controller.title}"
                            rendered="#{controller.icon==null}"/>
        </ice:commandLink>
```

But when I try to replace the component with the ace, the picture becomes not clickable, and the click is now triggered on that line, which is specified in the value (by defaul "Default Anchor Label"). How can a remove all text and make picture like a button?

In my case, I do not need to use the ice component and that the page does not reboot after I click the button.

Comment: So you post code of something that IS working but don't post the code you tried that is NOT working. Please add the latter as well.

Comment: The code that does not work almost does not differ. All I was trying to do was change the component ice:commandLink to h:commandLink(the picture is displayed correctly, but after clicking reloads the page) and ace:linkButton(the picture becomes not clickable). I tried to follow the guide that I found on icesoft.org (ICE to ACE Component Migration Guide).